# how to get sum of associative array with same key using php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a PHP array as follows.
I was trying to get the sum of values of the same array keys.
I want to get the sum of each key elements in the associative array using PHP. If anyone can help me, then it is more helpful for me. Thank you in advance.
And my code is like:

```php
  $arr = array();

  foreach ( $search as $srch_val => $srch_row){
    
   foreach ($srch_row as $key => $val) {

        if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)){
          $arr[$key] = $arr[$key] + array_sum($val);
          
        } else {
            $arr[$key] = array_sum($val);
        }
      }
 }
```

My array is like this:

```
Array(   
    [RED] => Array
            (
               [AP] => 2

            )

            [BLUE] => Array
            (
                 [OR] => 5
                 [GR] => 3
                 [PL] => 2
                 [BL] => 1
            )

            [YELLOW] => Array
            (
                [LI] => 7
                [OR] => 4
                [GR] => 3
                [PL] => 4
            )

            [GREEN] => Array
            (
                [GR] => 3
                [AP] => 2
                [PL] => 1
                [LI] => 2
            )

    [BLACK] => Array
        (
            [BL] => 4
            [GR] => 4
            [LI] => 3
        )

    [VIOLET] => Array
        (
            [PL] => 3
            [GR] => 2
            [LI] => 1
        )
      )
  Array
  (
      [ORANGE] => Array
          (
              [AV] => 5
              [BL] => 6
              [OR] => 2
              [LI] => 3
          )

      [GREEN] => Array
          (
              [LI] => 5
              [GR] => 6
              [AP] => 2
              [CB] => 3
          )

      [YELLOW] => Array
          (
              [LI] => 6
              [PL] => 5
              [OR] => 2
          )
  )
```

I want to get the sum of each key elements

My output like:

```
[AP] => 6
[OR] => 13
[GR] => 21
[PL] => 15
[BL] => 11
[LI] => 28
[AV] => 5
[CB] => 3
```

But I got the result with all keys containing zeros.

Comment: So you want a sum of all `red`, `blue` etc. or sum of all `BR`, `BL` etc.?  Maybe show a sample of the desired output.

Comment: I want sum of all AP,OR,GR etc    My output like

     [AP] => 6
     [OR] => 13
     [GR] => 21
     [PL] => 15
     [BL] => 11
     [LI] => 28
     [AV] => 5
     [CB] => 3

Comment: `$val` is a number not an array so get rid of the 2 `array_sum` and just use the `$val`.

Comment: No its not working. i added my code in top of the question. Can you check my code. From that code i got all keys with value 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$val` is a number not an array so get rid of the `array_sum` and just use the `$val`:

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($search as $srch_val => $srch_row) {
    foreach ($srch_row as $key => $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
            $arr[$key] = $arr[$key] + ($val);
        } else {
            $arr[$key] = ($val);
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/ZP0Zd).